# Best way to resolve escaped characters in a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have a populated mysql database that outputs json data which is consumed and displayed via angularjs.
Some of the text strings in the database have escaped quotes and double quotes like:

```
   Do you have at least a bachelor\'s degree in child development?
```

or

```
   asking the children to address you as \"Ma\'am\" or \"Sir\" to formalize things
```

The problem is angularjs still displays the strings with the escaped quotes. What is the best way to avoid this? Do I do a search and replace on the database substituting the escaped substrings (\',\") for something else?
The outputs are displayed in angularjs like so with a ng-model directive:

```
    ...
    <div class="bs form-group" ng-if="quiz.quizmanager.quiz.questions[quiz.activeQuestion].quiz_question_type === 'text'">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="quiz.quizmanager.quiz.questions[quiz.activeQuestion].answer"
               ng-change="quiz.selectAnswer(0, quiz.quizmanager.quiz.questions[quiz.activeQuestion].quiz_question_type)"
               />
    </div>
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, you could do a query like that, or you could use `stripslashes` before you output the data. How did it get like that to begin with, though? Did you escape it before binding it to a prepared statement to insert it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic The stripslashes wouldnt work as I am json_encoding an array before sending the response to angular. I still have the db insert statements. They look something like this:

Comment: (70,'Kickin\\\' Kitchens','Kickin\\\' Kitchens',0,0,'2017-07-06 00:00:00',NULL,0,'00:20:00'),

Comment: (90,9,'In the video, the concept of \\\\&#34;intersectionalism\\\\&#34; is defined as:','radio'),

Comment: Can you `stripslashes` on the text before adding it to the array you're going to `json_encode`? `json_encode` will add its own slashes again where they're needed.

Comment: WHat do I sustitute the strings \\\', \\\", \\\\&#34;, \\\\&#39; with

Comment: @Don'tPanic I cant add the stripslashes to the text first. I'm getting the data as arrays from the database:

Comment: You should still be able to. `$row['column'] = stripslashes($row['column'])`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing a search and replace thru the sql before repopulating the database